# SignalR chat not connecting to the Hub?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a signalr chatroom in asp.net I am getting the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined" and the prompt does not come up.
I followed this tutorial https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr with a modification to the startup class.

Startup.cs..

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MyTrainer.Startup))]
namespace MyTrainer
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            var config = new HubConfiguration();

            config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            config.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;

            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
        }
    }
}
```

My View (ChatRoom.cshtml)...

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ChatRoom";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Hub...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace MyTrainer
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller..

```
public ActionResult ChatRoom()
{
    return View();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was rendering fullcalendar scripts in the layout page that was messing with the scripts for signal r

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the error message when connecting to the server,you can add ".fail", one of the errors you may encounter is due to the version.

```
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            // Call the Send method on the hub.
            chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
            // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    }).fail(function (reason) {
        console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
    });
```